# Sql query for getting records by relation records count

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables n:m, and 1 relation table.

How can I find users who have min 2 and max 6 projects by join table?

```
Project {
  id
  title
}

User {
  id
  email
}

User_Project {
  id
  project_id
  user_id
}
```

Comment: You should share what you have tried.  And include a database tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need a query that finds users that have minimum 3 and maximum 6 projects.

Comment: Vitalii, What Database is this?. Also show us, data in those tables, what you need as output (as a set of records), and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You need to `group by` the fields you load and use a having `clause` to check your condition.

```
select User.id, User.email
from User
join User_Project
on User.id = User_Project.user_id
join Project
on User_Project.project_id = Project.id
group by User.id, User.email
having 3 <= count(*) and count(*) <= 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the user id, you don't need any joins at all:

```
select up.user_id
from User_Project up
group by up.user_id
having count(*) between 3 and 6;
```

If you need more information about the users, you can join in the `users` table.  I see no need for the `project` table to answer this question.